# Unable to create hierarchical rowTag while converting Dataframe into an XML using pyspark

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm using pyspark to convert dataframe into an xml file.
Below is my sample dataframe(df) -

```
Value     Year    Month   Day
------------------------------
con      2018     10      5    
tet      2017     7      14    
eco      2010     12      6
```

The out put XML would be -

```
<DataValue>
  <DataList>
     <Value> con </Value>
     <TimeStamp>
         <Year> 2018 </Year> 
         <Month> 10 </Month>
         <Day> 5 </Day>
     </TimeStamp>
   </DataList>

   <DataList>
     <Value> tet </Value>
     <TimeStamp>
         <Year> 2017 </Year> 
         <Month> 7 </Month>
         <Day> 14 </Day>
     </TimeStamp>
   </DataList>

   <DataList>
     <Value> eco </Value>
     <TimeStamp>
         <Year> 2010 </Year> 
         <Month> 12 </Month>
         <Day> 6 </Day>
     </TimeStamp>
   </DataList>
</DataValue>
```

I'm able to create the xml but not able to generate rowTag TimeStamp under rowtag DataList. Please assist.

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to solve my above problem. Please note we can only create a root tag and row tags. But there is no direct approach to create subtags inside rowtags. If you want to create any additional sub tag under row tag you have to create a structure and store in your dataframe column. 
In my above case I want Timestamp sub tag which contains Year Month and Day. So, I've defined a schema for those 3 fields and create an Array with that schema and add it in my dataframe. Finally when I converted that specific column (which coiontains the [yyyy, mm, dd] array) into an XML it appears as a sub tag. Hope this idea will help.